# Copying files from my project in Maven

Tags: maven

Is it possible to copy folders from my project to a certain location during some Maven phase?  Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Maven way of doing this would be using the `copy-resources` goal in `maven-resources-plugin`

From http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/extra-resources</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/non-packaged-resources</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: I would prefer this solution, before using the `ant-run` plugin.

Comment: Are there any benefits from using the maven resource plugin? I prefer doing this with the ant-run plugin because it allows you to handle single files and to rename them and it is a bit shorter - although it's still a lot of xml to write to simply copy a file...

Comment: @mort - no particular benefits. But my *personal* preference is to use Maven plugins where available rather than antrun.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid antrun? My opinion is that antrun is just a maven plugin like all the others. Furthermore, ant and maven together sometimes really do the best job.

Comment: "The Maven way" - something that should be a single line instead takes 30.

Answer (score 21):

Take a look at the maven-antrun plugin. You can copy a file in any maven phase like this:

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>copy</id>
          <phase>compile</phase>
          <configuration>
            <tasks>
              <copy file="myFileSource" tofile="MyFileDest"/>
            </tasks>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution> 
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I wanted exactly the one.

Comment: @BabannaDuggani Please note that `<tasks>` node is deprecated in maven-antun-plugin 1.5+. See the alternative here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35397606/363573

Answer (score 3):

A solution similar to [@mort's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3423759/363573) with **maven-antrun-plugin 1.8**:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <configuration>
        <target>
          <copy file="sourceFile" tofile="targetFile"/>
        </target>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution> 
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note that `<tasks>` node is deprecated in favor of `<target>` node as of **maven-antrun-plugin  1.5**.