# Maven specific copy task

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm a newbie in Maven and I would like to know. Is there any way I can write some task or plugin or something else for Maven in order to copy arbitrary (selected by myself) directories to classpath while building a simple Java SE project? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This question lists eight (!) approaches to copying files using Maven :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586202/best-practices-for-copying-files-with-maven

Comment: whereas this question just has one approach, but explained fully and very straightforwards.  I guess this is your best bet : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423737/copy-files-from-my-project-with-maven

Comment: what do you mean by arbitrary directories: 1) directories that contain java classes 2) directories that contain native code to be used by java 3) directories with resource files?

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I'll try every approach.

Answer (score 1):

Its an inbuilt feature in maven as you can use `maven-resources-plugin` and set the goal to `copy-resources`.

For more you can have a look at maven specs for this plugin [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html).

Thanks