# How to copy content from maven module target directory to the parent

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project which has 2 maven modules i.e module 1 and module 2. Below is the structure of the project

Parent

```
-- module 1
        -- pom.xml
-- module 2
        -- pom.xml
-- pom.xml
```

Now when i build the project, both module 1 and module 2 build directory will have a jar and xml file.

What i want to achieve is to have content of build directory of both module 1 and module 2 to be copied to a specific directory structure under parent when i build the project.

Please can you suggest on how i can achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [copy files from my project with maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423737/copy-files-from-my-project-with-maven)

Comment: I tried the approach suggested in that post but it didnot help.

Comment: Are you sure that copying files around between modules is what you want to do? You can probably use the maven-resources-plugin to achieve that but there might be a better way to achieve what you're trying to achieve without copying files around the place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use maven-resources-plugin to do this.

Configure it to copy all needed files to your wanted path, and bind the execution during the phase install of both module 1 and 2.

Doing this, when the module has just been compiled and artifacts produced, the resource plugin will execute and  copy your files.

You can find the documentation of the plugin here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html

Comment: I should define maven-resources-plugin in the module 1 and 2 pom.xml ?

Comment: Yes, if you need to copy files produced by module 1 and module 2, you need to call this plugin into each module