# How to move newly bundled jar file from target directory to custom location

Tags: xml, web-services, maven, ant

We using maven - please find below a excerpt of our pom.xml file.

Our current procedure ist:

1. stop the server : net stop "Macromedia JRun CFusion Server"
2. Move the new jar to server directory
   a.  Target Directory : C:\sha2Demo60Mvn\target\IbanWs-Client.jar
   b. Server Directory  :  C:\JRun4\servers\cfusion\cfusion-ear\cfusion-war\WEB-INF\lib\IbanWs-Client.jar
3. Start the server : net start "Macromedia JRun CFusion Server".

**Question :**

How we can copy the IbanWs-Client.jar file from target directory to acustom directory? The previously available jar file needs to removed and the new jar should be  copied. Please advise.

```xml
 <build>
        <finalName>IbanWs-Client</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.jks</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.keystore</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.jks</include>
                    <include>**/*.keystore</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: adds syntax highlighting  improves structure and explanation for what is asked

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423737/copying-files-from-my-project-in-maven might point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution to my question. I created a .bat file file to do what I need. Below is the .bat file content.

```
@Echo off
 pause
 net stop "Macromedia JRun CFusion Server" 
 pause
 copy  C:\sha2Demo60Mvn\target\IbanWs-Client.jar   C:\JRun4\servers\cfusion\cfusion-ear\cfusion-war\WEB-INF\lib\IbanWs-Client.jar
 pause
 net start "Macromedia JRun CFusion Server"
 pause
```

This script will stop the server if running ==> deploys the jar file ==> Starts the server. You need to place this .bat file in the server bin directory.